# what is the diff between setting transactionflowoption.mandatory and TransactionScopeOption.Required

Tags: wcf, transactions, wcf-binding

What is the difference between setting `TransactionFlowOption.Mandatory` and `TransactionScopeOption.Required`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically `TransactionFlowOption` and `TransactionScopeOption` refer to different things with `TransactionFlowOption` relating to whether an operation joins (or does not etc.) an existing (client-side-initiated for example) transaction while `TransactionScopeOption` can enforce that the operation is executed within a new (service-initiated) transaction...